# How to change user in json

Tags: json, shell, pm2

I have a pm2 process/service.so i want to start the service with pm2 start path/.json_file.
but here while executing these command i need to switch some certain user I have tried
"sudo -u " User" Pm2 start   /home/.json".
But it is throwing error. Can anyone help.

I have tried
sudo -u "redis" pm2 start /home/index.json